# Practical use for heritability value at sub-population level?

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, population, application, range

For me as a layperson, heritability is something that much smarter people than me calculate, and there are several questions already on the forum about how to do that (eg, [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/346111/294280) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/323928/294280)).  I understand that such heritability values say something about variance at the population level, and are useful in comparisons with one another.  However my question is, given a heritability value, what can one do with it in practice?

For example, suppose IQ had a known heritability (actual [heritability of IQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritability_of_IQ) has a wide possible range, but let's simplify), would it then be possible to say something like: Given a heritability of 50%, parents with average IQ of 100 have a XX% chance of having a child with IQ ranging from YYY-ZZZ?  Or given a heritability of 80%, parents with average height of 170cm have a XX% chance of having children YYY-ZZZcm tall?

Or is there some other way that heritability can have a practical application at a sub-population level?

Comment: 1/2 Quite relevant: Lewontin, R. C. (1974). [The analysis of variance and the analysis of causes](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article-pdf/35/3/520/2194964/dyl062.pdf). *American Journal of Human Genetics*, 26, 400–411.

Comment: 2/2 Morton, N. E. (1974). [Analysis of Family Resemblance. I. Introduction](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1762618/pdf/ajhg00..). *American Journal of Human Genetics*, 26(3), 318–330.

Comment: According to that first reference, the answer may be "no, this value is pretty much useless", or to quote directly: "Heritability is not a measure of the contributions of genes and environments to any individual phenotype, a fruitless enterprise as both are subsumed within the processes of development."